# Not getting value in <c:set var from scriptlet variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am defining a variable in scriptlet to get value from request headers, then we are using that variable c:set to set to variable to use in c:out .But i am not getting any value c:set variable, as a result c:out is giving result as ''.

please find the code snippet below and guide me if i am missing anything.

Code in jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DM</title>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
function submitform()
{
    this.LoginForm.submit();     
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body onload="submitform()">


<% 
String userName= request.getHeader("IV-USER");
System.out.println("name "+userName);
if (userName == null || userName.length()==0){
        response.setHeader("IV-USER",userName);
        response.sendRedirect("ULM.jsp");
}
%>
<c:set var="uName" value="<%=userName%>"/>
<p>Welcome1 ${uName}</p>
<form  name="LoginForm" action="/ICDDMContent/STGDM.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value='<c:out value="${uName}"/>'/>
<!--
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="<%=userName%>" >
-->
<input type="hidden" name="Token" value="dummy">
<p>Welcome1 <c:out value="${uName}"/></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking that 'IV-USER' header is actually not empty

Comment: And by the way, you can access header from el, just use ${header['IV-USER']}

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.We tried this and worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
String userName= request.getHeader("IV-USER");
System.out.println("name "+userName);
if (userName == null || userName.length()==0){
        response.setHeader("IV-USER",userName);
        response.sendRedirect("ULM.jsp");
}
```

Is redundant piece of code, if userName is empty, you will just assign empty value to IV-USER header, if "ULM.jsp" is the same page as you've attached, and that redirect is just to set variable - here is your problem

Comment: ULM.jsp is different page.